# Issue while querying a alias column in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to solve this using ORACLE query. Following is the sample data

```
|     Col1       |      Col2    |
------------------------------------
| 21-dec-15      | nochange     |
| 20-dec-15      | change       |
| 20-dec-15      | nochange     | 
| 18-dec-15      | change       |
| 18-dec-15      | nochange     |
```

Here col2 is a alias column, not a column from table.

Here the requirement is for a particular date I need to check whether any change is happening, If change is there then update `nochange` to `change` for that date.

As col2 is a alias column so I am not sure how to check it. I am also ok if we are storing the result in a separate alias column.

Expected Result:

```
|     Col1       |      Col2  |
------------------------------------
| 21-dec-15      | nochange     |
| 20-dec-15      | change       |
| 20-dec-15      | change       | 
| 18-dec-15      | change       |
| 18-dec-15      | change       |
```

Comment: What is a "reference column"?

Comment: It's an alias column..edited..

Comment: Still don't get it - what is an "alias column"?  Do you mean it is computed in the select statement like `select case when ... then 'change' else 'nochange' end`?

Comment: From your expected result, do you mean that if there is only 1 row with same  col1 value then show 'nochange', if more than 1 show 'change'?

Comment: Exactly..In the select clause...

Comment: @ tony No..not like that......i have to check whether `change` is happening for a particular date...then update all rows with same date as 'change'.

Comment: How do you check whether a change is happening?

Comment: I think, I need to check whether a row has value `change`, then check for date, then update all rows for that date....Im not sure whether in this way query will work...

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand the requirements!

Comment: Basically I need to capture all `change` values from `col2`,  get the dates , and all the dates which we get, i have to update the corresponding col2  with 'change'....

Comment: Please show table schema definition.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
with tempt as 
(
   <<Your existing query that returns col1 and col2>>
)
select t1.col1,
       case when exists ( select 1 from tempt t2 where t1.col1=t2.col1 and t2.col2='change')
            then 'change'
            else t1.col2
       end
  from tempt t1;
```

Add an order by col1 if needed.